@mui/icons-material + Vitest ES Module Issue
I'm migrating our test suite from Jest to Vitest. All tests work except for a remaining few which result in this error:
Module /home/d/code/frontend/node_modules/@mui/icons-material/esm/VisibilityOff.js:3 seems to be an ES Module but shipped in a CommonJS package. You might want to create an issue to the package "@mui/icons-material" asking them to ship the file in .mjs extension or add "type": "module" in their package.json.

As a temporary workaround you can try to inline the package by updating your config:

// vitest.config.js
export default {
  test: {
    server: {
      deps: {
        inline: [
          "@mui/icons-material"
        ]
      }
    }
  }

I've tried the suggested solution to no avail.
I've also tried
resolve: {
alias: [
  { find: '/@src', replacement: './src' },
  {
    find: /^@mui\/icons-material\/(.*)/,
    replacement: '@mui/icons-material/esm/$1',
  },
],
},

I've tried

  optimizeDeps: {
    include: ['@mui/icons-material'],
  },

I've tried:
resolve: {
    alias: {
      "@mui/icons-material": "@mui/icons-material/esm",
    },
  },


I've tried changing the rollup options
const baseRollupOptions: RollupOptions = {
   external: ['fs/promises', '@mui/icons-material'],
}

I've tried
  deps: {
    optimizer: {
      web: {
        include: [
          'react-cookie',
          'redux-signalr',
          '@mui/x-charts',
          '@babel/runtime',
          'd3-color',
          'd3-format',
          'd3-interpolate',
          'd3-scale',
          'd3-shape',
          'd3-time',
          'd3-time-format',
          'd3-path',
          'd3-array',
          'internmap',
          '@mui/icons-material',
        ],
        exclude: [
          'node_modules/(?!(@mui/icons-material|react-cookie|redux-signalr|@mui/x-charts|@babel/runtime|d3-(color|format|interpolate|scale|shape|time|time-format|path|array)|internmap)/)',
        ],
      },
    },
    external: [
      'node_modules/(?!(react-cookie|redux-signalr|@mui/x-charts|@babel/runtime|d3-(color|format|interpolate|scale|shape|time|time-format|path|array)|internmap)/)',
    ],
  },

No option appears to be working currently.
Curiously the tests that are failing do not seem to even use this particular mui icon. I also have other tests that run that do use that icon.
I've also ensured I cleared the cache before running the test each time (rm -rf node_modules/.vite)

Just a shot in the dark, but did you try setting both the alias and the server.deps.inline at the same time?
I've had a similar issue and this is what helped me:
import { defineConfig } from 'vitest/config';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react() as any],
  test: {
    // ...
    
    alias: [
      {
        find: /^@mui\/icons-material\/(.*)/,
        replacement: '@mui/icons-material/esm/$1',
      },
    ],
    server: {
      deps: {
        inline: true,
        // or
        inline: ['@my/libA'],
      },
    },
  },
});

You'll probably want to try changing inline: true to something more specific as I guess it has some performance implications (https://vitest.dev/config/#server-deps-inline).
In my case trying your original line of inline: ['@mui/icons-material'] failed to fix it.
I had a custom esm library @my/libA in-between the import chain "@mui/icons-material -> @my/libA -> @my/appB; Setting inline: ['@my/libA'] is what worked for me.
My original error was something like this though:
SyntaxError: Named export 'ArrowForward' not found. 
The requested module '@mui/icons-material' is a CommonJS module, 
which may not support all module.exports as named exports.
CommonJS modules can always be imported via the default export, for example using:

import pkg from '@mui/icons-material';


Btw, is the error you posted the one before you applied any alias to @mui/icons-material or was it the one above?

What worked for me was:
    resolve: {
      mainFields: ["module", "main"],
    }
    test: {
      server: {
        deps: {
          inline: [
            // ... any other dependency that imports @mui/icons-material
            "@mui/icons-material",
            "clsx",
          ],
        },
      },

